# java login and add new user program

Tags: java, arrays, authentication

I need the solution to these errors for this login program and the follow up code to add a new user.
many Thanks.

I need the solution to these errors for this login program and the follow up code to add a new user.
many Thanks.

I need the solution to these errors for this login program and the follow up code to add a new user.
many Thanks.

```
package coursework111;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author mcq13065590
 */
public class Coursework111 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

   // This will populate the contacts array
   // Case sensitive   

    String[] contacts = new String[10];

    contacts [0] = "polyMay3378";
    contacts [1] = "john1234567";
    contacts [2] = "Sue22banks";
    contacts [3] = "carrieOak45";

    // This will populate the passwords array
    // Case sensitive 
    String[] passwords = new String[10];

    passwords[0]= "Passw123";
    passwords[1]= "DoneTell4";
    passwords[2]= "eASYHac3";
    passwords[3]= "TPd7aqD4";

    // This will populate the memData array
    // Case sensitive 
    String[] memData = new String[10];

    memData[0]= "flower23";
    memData[1]= "Belfast1";
    memData[2]= "Beach575";
    memData[3]= "Salou567";

    // variables stated 

    String pass;
    String user;


    double randomNumber1;
    double randomNumber2;
    double randomNumber3;

    int index = 0;
    boolean vaildUser = false, vaildPass = false;

    // memorable data char variables

    char char1, char2, char3;

    boolean char1Valid = false;
    boolean char2Valid = false;
    boolean char3Valid = false;


    // add a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

    // Main Menu presented to the user

    System.out.println("Welcome to ");
    System.out.println("1 Login ");
    System.out.println("2 Add a new user ");

    int choice = input.nextInt();

    if(choice==1)
    {

        System.out.println("Please enter your username");
        user = input.next();

        for (int i=0; i < contacts.length; i++)

             if(user.equals(contacts[i]))
            {
                index = i;
                vaildUser = true;
            }        



        System.out.println("Please enter your password");
        pass = input.next();


        for (int i=0; i < passwords.length; i++)

            if(pass.equals(passwords[index]))
            {
                vaildPass = true;
            }        


         // adding random char input



       randomNumber1 = (int)(Math.random()*8+1);
       randomNumber2 = (int)(Math.random()*8+1);
       randomNumber3 = (int)(Math.random()*8+1);


        System.out.println("Please enter characrer" + randomNumber1  + "from your memerable data");

        char1 = input.next().charAt(0);

       if(char1== memData.charAt(randomNumber1))

        {

             char1Valid = true;   

        }


        System.out.println("Please enter characrer" + randomNumber2  + "from your memerable data");

        char2 = input.next().charAt(0);

        if(char2== memData.charAt(randomNumber2))

         {

            char2Valid = true;

        }

        System.out.println("Please enter characrer" + randomNumber3  + "from your memerable data");

        char3 = input.next().charAt(0);

        if(char3== memData.charAt(randomNumber3))

         {

            char3Valid = true;

        }


        if(vaildPass== true && vaildUser== true && char1Valid== true && char2Valid== true && char3Valid== true)

        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to SWC Bank.");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
        }
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Did you copy paste the same line three times just to make enough text to post the question? Not a good idea.

Comment: You're breaking several of SOs general rules for asking questions here...

Answer (score 0):

Please say what you have tried and what do you expect exactly next time. Stack overflow community is a helpful community but not a code error finding service.

In this case, you have this block wrong.

```
/*memData is a string array
* You can only use the charAt method for a string, NOT for an array.
**/
if(char1== memData.charAt(randomNumber1)) {
    char1Valid = true;   
}
```